# Error encountered when using lambda to change variable values

Tags: c#, variables, lambda

I'm trying to calculate the values when one variable has another variable in the formula. I've used the lambda approach as suggested by [@Rain366](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4977546/rain336), however, this approach has a limitation and I received this error,

`Error  CS0200  Property or indexer 'Class3.Storage.b' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`.

I've tried using the get and set approach `public static int b { get; set; } => a + 5;`, but I believe the method of doing it is wrong. Is there a way to use lambda to write values or possibly merge it with a setter?

What I would like to see is the value of b constantly updating itself (therefore I've used the lambda approach) and the flexibility of editing the value of b by using something like `Storage.b++;`

Thank you!

Code as shown below.

```
class Class3
{
public class Storage
    {
        public static int a = 100;
        public static int b => a + 5;
        public static int c;
    }
public static void Main()
    {
        Methods Test = new Methods();
        Console.WriteLine("Original a value: {0}", Storage.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", Storage.b);
        Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", Storage.c);
        Test.Met1();
        Console.WriteLine("After met1: {0}", Storage.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", Storage.b);
        Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", Storage.c);
        Test.Met2();
        Console.WriteLine("After met2: {0}", Storage.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", Storage.b);
        Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", Storage.c);
        Test.Met3();
        Console.WriteLine("After met3: {0}", Storage.a);
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", Storage.b);
        Console.WriteLine("c value: {0}", Storage.c);

        Storage.b += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("b value: {0}", Storage.b);
    }
    public class Methods
    {
        public void Met1()
        {
            Storage.a -= 10;
            Storage.c = Storage.a;
        }
        public void Met2()
        {
            Storage.a -= 10;
            Storage.c = Storage.a;
        }
        public void Met3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Storage.a);
            Storage.c = Storage.a;
            Met1();
            Met2();
            if (Storage.a > 10)
            {
                Met3();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

read only means you can only read :D 
so try this:

```
private static int _f = a + 5;
    public static int f
    {
        get { return _f; }
        set { _f = a + 5; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Zdenek, Thank you for helping. I have tried get and set before, but using this method doesn't change the values of `b` whenever the value of `a` changes. That was why I used lambda. Is there a way to use get, set and lambda together?